# Interacting with _tests variable in unittest.suite

Tags: python, unit-testing, automation, automated-tests, python-unittest

I'm creating a solution that scales based on the number of tests in a Python unittest Test Suite. I need to access the number of tests I've selected to run, whether that's just one or a whole class of tests. I see these test names available when I run in debug mode under _handleClassSetUp, suite.py:163, under the variable named self _tests, but I've been unable to interact with it or select it when trying to reference it from my setUpClass(cls) method.

I am able to get the tests from the class by using number_tests = cls.countTestCases(cls) in the setUpClass method, but this doesn't change if I run only one test as it selects all from that class I'm running.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Likely, you want to implement a `TestRunner` which does the counting (or use some sort of discography and count the tests there).  In any case, this stuff likely happens _before_ your tests start running.  The real question though, is why do you want to know this?

Comment: As mentioned, I'm creating a solution that scales based on the number of tests and other variables specified by the user.

Comment: That doesn't really make any sense to me without seeing an example :-).  Unit tests run tests.  Each test should be isolated.  It really doesn't matter how many there are (other than more tests take longer to run I suppose)...